# iText x and y position of the text incorrect

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a huge PDF document (1600 pages) from which I kept only a part of it by printing some pages in Acrobat Reader.

I am reading the text using iText with the following code:

```
public void decode(File file) throws IOException {
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file.toURI().toURL());
   int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
   ProcessorListener listener = new ProcessorListener();
   PdfContentStreamProcessor processor = new PdfContentStreamProcessor(listener);
   for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= numberOfPages; pageNumber++) {
      PdfDictionary resourcesDic = pageDic.getAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
      processor.processContent(ContentByteUtils.getContentBytesForPage(reader, pageNumber), resourcesDic);
   } 
}
```

and the processor:

```
public class ProcessorListener implements RenderListener {
   private final PdfReader reader;

   public ProcessorListener(PdfReader reader) {
      this.reader = reader;
   }

   @Override
   public void beginTextBlock() {
   }

   @Override
   public void renderText(TextRenderInfo tri) {
      String text = tri.getText();
      double x = tri.getDescentLine().getBoundingRectange().getX();
      double y = tri.getDescentLine().getBoundingRectange().getY();
      System.out.println(text + " => x:" + x + " y:" + y);   
   }

   @Override
   public void endTextBlock() {
   }
}
```

What I observe is that in my initial (huge) document, the x and y coordinates change depending on the text position, but in my smaller saved document the coordinates of all texts are almost always the same (x is very small and y is big), in my case, for example x is invariably smaller than 2, and y is always almost equal to 480.

What's the reason for this behavior? I only have this problem if I print my PDF document using Acrobat Reader, not when I am printing it using Edge for example. Also the resulting document  is correctly shown in Acrobat Reader or Edge, which is the reason I think that the problem is in my code.

Comment: Why do you take the `BoundingRectangle` of the `DescentLine`? Depending on the orientation of the text that will render the results senseless. Other than that, please share your _smaller saved document_ to allow reproducing the issue.

Comment: Hello, how am I able to share a (small) document on StackOverflow?

Comment: stack overflow does not have a feature for sharing arbitrary files. Simply, therefore, create a public share on some file sharing platform (e.g. a dropbox or google drive public share) and post the link here.